# Unable to replace form with message on submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created an HTML5 form, which incorporates reCAPTCHA, and I've also written a PHP script that sends an email when the form is submitted. At the moment, the script redirects the user to an error or thankyou page, but I'm trying to adjust it to dynamically replace the form within a message within the same page.

I've tried the following script, but it displays the message as soon as the page loads, before any user interaction.

**PHP/HTML:**

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {

// Load reCAPTCHA library
include_once ("autoload.php");

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$emailFrom = $email;
$emailTo = "my@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Request";

// Prepare email body text
$body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br /> <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br /> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

$secret = 'XXX';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo 'Your message was submitted!';

} else {
?>
<div class="contact-form">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
        <label for="name"><span>Name</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your name." /></label>
        <label for="email"><span>Email</span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your email address." /></label>
        <label for="message"><span>Message</span><textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your message."></textarea></label>
        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><div id="recaptcha"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcBawsTAAAAAKBPfGs1jApXNRLvR2MIPng0Fxol"></div></div></label>
        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="" class="submit-button" /></label>                  
    </form>             
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

I'm new to PHP, so I'm not sure if it's a syntax or semantics issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if(POST) { ` is `POST` a constant?...or Which script are you using currently?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Still kinda new at this. I'm using the first script, but I'll use whatever works.

Comment: `POST` is not `$_POST`, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php. You're comparing an undefined constant (as I read it), which will be false so you always get the form. You should probably give your submit button the `name` attribute and check that that value `isset`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fixed the syntax and it worked! Thanks a lot! However, instead of displaying the message on the spot, the page is reloaded and scrolled back to the top. Is this a limit of PHP or my script? Doesn't make for a great UX.

Comment: Not sure about that, it shouldn't do that... Can you update the question to your current code? Shouldn't something be done with `$resp`?

Comment: Just updated. Ah, yes, now that you mention it, I was originally using this if statement, but someone suggested taking it out, but now I'm not sure where to include it: http://pastebin.com/pKV6AKEL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87843/discussion-between-chris85-and-mario-parra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

Check to see if the form has been submitted with `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. You can also use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` to see if the form has been submitted.

Then we check if the email has been successfully sent, and if it has we set the `$success_message` variable.

We then check to see if the `$success_message` variable is set, and if it isn't, we show the form.

Also, note that I added `name="submit"` to the submit button element. This is how we're checking to see if the form has been submitted.

I also changed `stripslashes()` to `strip_tags()` to prevent any malicious code from getting through.

```
<?php

// Load reCAPTCHA library
include_once ("autoload.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $message = trim(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
    $emailFrom = $email;
    $emailTo = "my@email.com";
    $subject = "Contact Request";

    // Prepare email body text
    $body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br /> <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br /> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

    $secret = 'XXX';
    $lang = 'en';
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


    // EDIT: repositioned recaptcha from OP's PasteBin script, as requested and adjusted messaging
    // changed $success var to $message and added error message

    // Original if statement, which redirected the user
    if($resp->isSuccess()){

        // send the email
        if(mail($emailFrom, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

            // set the success message
            $success_message = 'The form was sent! Yay!';

        } else {

            // error message
            $error_message = 'Could not send email';
        }
    } else {
        $error_message = 'Prove you are a human!';
    }
}
?>
<div>
    <!-- quick and dirty way to print messages -->
    <?php if(isset($success_message)) { echo $success_message; } ?>
    <?php if(isset($error_message)) { echo $error_message; } ?>
</div>

<?php if(!isset($success_message)): ?>
<div class="contact-form">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
        <label for="name"><span>Name</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your name." /></label>
        <label for="email"><span>Email</span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your email address." /></label>
        <label for="message"><span>Message</span><textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your message."></textarea></label>

        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcBawsTAAAAAKBPfGs1jApXNRLvR2MIPng0Fxol"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php echo $lang; ?>">
        </script>

        <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="submit-button" /></label>                  
    </form>             
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Before I test this, as chris85 pointed out, I'm not including `$resp` in the `$success` variable. Do you know how I'd add that to your script?

Comment: Sorry, I actually missed that part! If the ReCaptcha is checking to see if it was POSTed properly, then you probably need to move that back inside `if($_POST['submit'])`. I was more concerned with getting your logic correct regarding checking for `POST`, sending the email and showing the form. Sorry I can't be more help on the ReCaptcha part.

Comment: You may not need to move `$resp` inside the SUBMIT check because it seems to have it's own check for `$_POST`. Try it both ways and see what happens?

Comment: This was my original script that used `$resp` and redirected the user to a separate page when the form was submitted: http://pastebin.com/pKV6AKEL. Could we use this script to adjust yours?

Comment: Hmm reCAPTCHA aside, I don't think the script is working. When the form is submitted, it just refreshes the page.

Comment: Are you actually sending email? It will always show the form unless the email is sent.

Comment: No, it's not sending an email anymore. Not sure why.

Comment: I had the wrong `$email` variable in the `mail()` function. Try it again. Also, to make it easier you can just change the `mail()` function to something really simple for testing.

Comment: That's sending the email and displaying the message, but ignoring the reCAPTCHA. The structure is a little different to my original script, so I'm not sure how/where to add `($resp->isSuccess())`. Do you know?

Comment: Actually, the structure is pretty much identical to your original script - because this is your script. :) I just added a couple pieces of logic and updated some of your functions. Was the ReCaptcha element working for you before?

Comment: I mean this (http://pastebin.com/pKV6AKEL) script, when the form used to redirect to a separate page. Yeah, it was working and loading the error and thankyou pages correctly if the box was checked or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87844/discussion-between-timgavin-and-mario-parra).